Custom Domain Configuration in Managed Cloud PaaS 2.0
Background

Version: Sitecore 10.4
Topology: XM
Rendering: Traditional Asp.NET MVC
Multisite: Yes (1 public and 1 authenticated)
Managed Cloud: PaaS 2.0, Azure Front Door Standard
SXA: No

Domains

www.clientname.com -> CD
portal.clientname.com -> CD
mgmt.clientname.com -> CM
id.clientname.com -> SI

Problem Statement
The CD App service is behind Azure Front Door.  Within Front Door, I've setup my two custom domains for this app service and generated AFD-managed certificates for these two domains so that I don't have to worry about renewals.
Additionally, I've setup the custom domains on the CD App Service itself using self-signed certificates generated within Azure Key Vault (also so I don't have to worry about renewals) and bound them to the custom domains for the CD App Service.
I've configured environment variables within my app service to match up with site configuration like so:
Public Site
<site name="mainsite" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
            targetHostName="$(env:CD_HOST)"
            hostName="$(env:CD_HOST)"
            database="web" 
            ...
/>

Authenticated Site
<site name="authenticatedSite" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
            targetHostName="$(env:AUTHENTICATED_HOST)"
            hostName="$(env:AUTHENTICATED_HOST)"
            database="web" 
            ... 
/>

When I attempt to browse to these sites with the environment variables set in the App Service, Sitecore is unable to find the site context and I end up with Sitecore Betty from the website site.  When I remove the environment variables, leaving the hostname attribute empty, Sitecore does properly render the site.
I'm seeing similar issues when attempting to bind custom domains to the CM and SI roles.  I know there's something simple that I'm missing and my hunch is that it has to do with the self-signed certificates.
Why is this so difficult setting up custom domains behind Azure Front Door?  What am I doing wrong?

You might be overriding the host header in the origin host header configuration. The documentation says:

If the request was made for www.contoso.com, and your origin contoso-westus.azurewebsites.net has an empty header field, Front Door sets the host header as www.contoso.com.


Most app backends (Azure Web Apps, Blob storage, and Cloud Services) require the host header to match the domain of the backend. However, the frontend host that routes to your origin uses a different hostname such as www.contoso.net.


If your origin requires the host header to match the origin hostname, make sure that the origin host header includes the hostname of the origin.


Custom Domains in Managed Cloud PaaS 2.0
Configuring custom domains in Managed Cloud's new Hub and Spoke architecture requires several additional steps that are not required for public-facing App Services.
If you're tasked with setting up custom domains for your Paas 2.0 Sitecore implementation and not an Azure Solutions Architect, this article will help you take the steps to configure your domains.
SSL Certificates
The first thing to know is that you won't be able to use Azure Front Door Managed Certificates or App Service Managed Certificates.
I found it easiest to work with a wildcard certificate that was procured separately through a Certificate Authority.
The second important note here is that I chose to store the certificate in the provided Azure Key Vault so that I can easily update it in one place before expiration.
Domain Configuration
Next you will need to decide on your domain naming strategy.
Depending on your available certificates, you'll likely want
To keep your subdomains to 3.
A typical domain strategy looks like this:
Traditional MVC site

Content Delivery: [dev|qa|www].clientname.com
Content Managment: [dev-|qa-]mgmt.clientname.com
Sitecore Identity: [dev-|qa-]id.clientname.com

Headless

Content Delivery: [dev-|qa-]content.clientname.com
Content Managment: [dev-|qa-]mgmt.clientname.com
Sitecore Identity: [dev-|qa-]id.clientname.com

DNS
Next up you'll need to configure DNS to point to Azure Front Door.
Before you can complete this step, you will need to request at least one environment from Managed Cloud so that they can create the HUB resource group with your Azure Front Door resources.  You'll get one front door for your pre-prod environments and the other for production.  Login to Azure and select the appropriate Azure Front Door resource.  Under Overview -> Endpoints, you'll see the Azure Front Door url.  This is what you'll use to configure DNS CNAMES.

HUB Configuration
Key Vault Certificate
Azure Front Door

Secrets - Import Key Vault Certificate
Domains
Origin Route
Origin Group

SPOKE Configuration
App Services

Certificates (import from Key Vault first)
Custom Domains

Application Gateway

Link Key Vault Certificate to Listener TLS Certificates - This must be done with Powershell since the Key Vault is in a different Azure subscription from the Spoke's Application Gateway.
az network application-gateway ssl-cert create --gateway-name <<Gateway Name>>
                                          --name <<Certificate Name>>
                                          --subscription <<subscription-id>>
                                          --resource-group <<Resource Group Name>>
                                          --key-vault-secret-id <<kv-secret-id>>



